# Is there any possibility of inheritance for wsdl files?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java

I would like to ask if is there any way to extend one WSDL by another? 
I have a project, which consists of a few modules and one of them is "Common". I would like to something like an abstract WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="AbstarctService"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
              xmlns:tns="urn:com:myProject:abstract"
              targetNamespace="urn:com:myProject:abstract">

    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <wsdl:import namespace="urn:com:myProject:abstract" location="AbstractService.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="myMessage">
        <wsdl:part name="fault" element="tns:messageInfo"/>
    </wsdl:message>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

I would like to use a message from this abstract in other services (all my services use the same class to handle errors), so the best way for me will be to "extend" AbstractService.wsdl

Comment: The message content is defined on the `<schema>`, so you're really asking if you can reuse a schema? Of course, you just `import` it.